# Error when a named parameter used multiple times in JDBC PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I get an error when use named parameter to call PL/SQL block, when all named parameters are used only once, then my code works fine, but when I dupplicate the SQL marked with "// the SQL". then all named parameters (starts with colon, :q) are used twice, now I get a SQL Exception, it says: The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters.
  It seems that JDBC driver or DB think there is 2 parameters, but only 1 parameters are registered? why we cannot use a named parameter multiple times? is JDBC driver don't required to support this case?
  How I get an alternative (exeption rewriting PL/SQL block to stored procedure)?

My Oracle JDBC Driver is latest version 11.2.0.3.0.

Because my project have many PL/SQL block, I try my best to avoid rewrite SQL to a stored procedure, running raw PL/SQL block with named  parameter (just treat it as a procedure) is preferred. I tested convert the PL/SQL block to a stored procedure, then only 1 parameters exported, but I don't want to rewrite all PL/SQL blocks, it takes more efforts.

thanks for any hints.

My Java code:

```
CallableStatement stmt = ...;
stmt.registerOutParameter("q", Types.VARCHAR);
stmt.execute();
String v1 = stmt.getString("q");
```

SQL as below:

```
BEGIN
    select DUMMY into :q from dual where dummy = 'X';
    select DUMMY into :q from dual where dummy = 'X';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

I just found that "Execute Immediate" can be used for my case, when the dynamic SQL is a PL/SQL block (quoted with begin and end), then the named parameters with a name can be referenced by all occurrences. i.e. SQL attached below, in this block, parameter 'q' is used only once, 
   but now I have another 2 questions, 
   Q1: I don't know if the parameter 'q' is IN, OUT or both IN and OUT. If I give wrong IN/OUT mode, error got, how we test if the parameter is IN/OUT or both of them? I want to scan the SQL for ':q :=' and 'into :q', it seems that it is not good method.
   Q2: Why I can't fetch result of parameter 'q' when it is assigned IN OUT mode? only if it is OUT, I can get its value. when it is both IN OUT, I get NULL.

```
begin
  execute immediate 'begin select dummy into :q from dual where :q is not null; end;'
  using in out :q;
end;
```

Oh, I get a workaround for NULL when parameter is IN OUT mode, I just treat it is a bug of Oracle JDBC driver, I split IN/OUT role of the named parameter 'q' into 2 parts, first is IN, second is OUT, using a variable to keep its value returned by 'using in out :q' clause, and then assign variable to 2nd role, like below-attached, in JDBC we treat it both IN OUT, only use exact IN,OUT or IN OUT in USING clause after scanning ' :q := ' and ' into :q '.

```
declare 
    p varchar2(100);
    q varchar2(100);
begin
    p := ?;
    q := ?;
    execute immediate 'begin if :p is null then :p := ''X''; else :p := ''Y''; :q := ''Z''; end if; end;' using in out p, out q;
    ? := p;
    ? := q;
end;
```

Comment: You registered them both as **out** parameters (`registerOutParameter`), it seems than one is an **in** parameter (qord)

Comment: @A.B.Cade If I removed the IN parameter :qord, I get same error, it seems that not IN/OUT type affect the result, but the named parameter are used multiple times, and jdbc driver/DB count parameter using parameters' position other than names. In latest oracle driver, it says, parameter count is different from registered parameter count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use one bind parameter multiple times in SQL statement.  You must provide a value for each occurrence of parameter.  This is because Oracle ignores bind parameter name and only a colon symbol is taken into account.
[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA)

Comment: But I'm doubting that why Oracle Forms can run this PL/SQL block as  expected. My target is directly run raw PL/SQL block of legacy Oracle Forms system in JDBC without rewriting them to stored procedure. In legacy Oracle Forms form, oracle run this PL/SQL block and fetch OUT parameters and push to UI fields. In the PL/SQL block, named parameters can share same values, if we bind them one-by-one by parameter position, them oracle treat them different parameters, and therefore when I try to callableStatement.getXXX(index), the return value may be unexpected. Don't know which occurrence is4 OUT.

Comment: After we registerOutputParameter, we can still setXX with same index, then oracle treat the parameter at the index as INOUT, without reading the PL/SQL block by eyes, we can't detect which occurrence is read-only and which occurrence is OUT(update). How Oracle Form works using same PL/SQL block?