# Dealing with PLSQL "IN OUT" parameter in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, parameters, plsql, procedure

I am calling the following `PL/SQL` procedure using `JDBC`. One of parameters is of type `IN OUT`.

```
PROCEDURE update_emp_commpct(emp_id IN employees.employee_id%type , new_comm_pct_incr IN OUT employees.commission_pct%type);
```

I was curious to know if this type of parameter should be treated differently from the other types. A [post in this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641333/writing-an-anonymous-pl-sql-block-with-bind-variables-using-jdbc) pointed me to [this oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefjdbc75719.html):

Its says the following

> For INOUT parameters, it is good practice to register the output
>   parameter before setting its input value.

**Why is registering the output before setting it input value a good practice ? Can someone elaborate on this ?** I tried both ways and the result is the same.

Also it says:

> INOUT parameters map to an array of the parameter type in Java

**I fail to understand this. Why does IN OUT parameter map to Array parameter in Java ?** Am I missing something here ? In the code that I tried out below I mapped it to java.sql.Numeric.

```
public float updateEmpCommpct(int empId , float incrementVal)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    float newCommPct = -1f;

    try 
    {
        // Registering the JDBC Driver
        // Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_ORACLE);

        // Creating a database connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PWD);

        // Creating a sql string
        String callProc = "{ call HR.EMP_PKG.update_emp_commpct(? , ?)}";

        // Create a callable statement
        callStmt = conn.prepareCall(callProc);

        // Bind Values to the IN parameters
        callStmt.setInt(1, empId);



        // Dealing with IN/OUT parameter
           // (1) Register the OUT parameter first
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
           // (2) Now bind a value to it
        callStmt.setFloat(2, incrementVal);

        // Execute the callable statement
        callStmt.execute();

        // Get the value of the OUT parameter
        newCommPct = callStmt.getFloat(2);
        System.out.println("Employee with Id : "+ empId + " has his commission percentage updated to: " + newCommPct);
    } 
    catch (SQLException se) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in the database");
        System.out.println("Exception message: "+ se.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Database error code: "+ se.getErrorCode());
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up
        if(callStmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                callStmt.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException se2) 
            {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(conn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException se2) 
            {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return newCommPct;
}
```

Comment: The link you pointed concerns **javadb** - in other words **Derby database** and it's driver implementation => https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/. You need rather follow this link (for Oracle Database 10.x JDBC driver): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/toc.htm if you are using Oracle database

Comment: It not mentioned any where in the doc. I guess the url say javadb . Nice catch.